# How to pack a firmware update image

Tags: rom-flashing, rom, device-firmware, android-tv

I've downloaded a several firmware versions to install on android tv stick to take it out of its boot loop.

I need to firmware packed as an update.img file and all the firmwares I've downloaded are in the form of a zip file with the following structure inside:

```
update.zip\
  |-META-INF\
  |   |-com\
  |   |-CERT.RSA
  |   |-CERT.SF
  |   |-MANIFEST.MF
  |-recovery\
  |   |-etc\
  |   |-recovery-from-boot.p
  |-system\
  |   |-app\
  |   |-bin\
  |   |-etc\
  |   |-fonts\
  |   |-framework\
  |   |-lib\
  |   |-media\
  |   |-tts\
  |   |-usr\
  |   |-vendor\
  |   |-xbin\
  |   |-build.prop
  |-boot.img
```

*Note: I'm only showing two levels for clarity, it's not that those folders are empty.*

**Does anyone recognizes that directory structure? Can I create an update.img pack out of it? If so, how?**

IMPORTANT: I need the new firmware in that format because Rockchip Batch Tool is the only way I have to install it my android tv stick.